# More targeted DNS Poisoning

Tags: security, networking, dns

I want to play around with DNS poisoning to see what I can do with it, how it works, etc. Unfortunately, the only tools I know of that poison the DNS cache go the whole mile and do a full MiTM attack, which I am not interested in doing right now.

Does anyone know of some software I can use that changes the cached IP for only specific sites and allows me to choose what I change it to (so that, in theory, I could redirect everyone on a network to Bing whenever they tried to use Google)?

Open source software would be best, but if there isn't any that's OK too.

All connections are wireless with no modems on a non-switched WiFi network. I don't care how the DNS server is attacked by the tool. I would like this to work with Windows or Linux, but if it only works with one or the other that's OK too.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/make-dns-spoof-python) describes how to perform DNS spoofing *rather than poisoning* using Man-in-the-Middle techniques for individual machines & domains using [python](https://python.org) + [scapy](https://scapy.net/).

- Free
- Open Source
- Linux machine needed but once in place should be able to impact all targets
- Targeted & Selective